# Ruby Gem for generation of unique anD not changeable URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Can someone suggest me the gem in ruby that generates URL which will be unique and not changeable for each individual .

Comment: It's not clear what are you real requirements. Any URL that includes immutable unique user's attribute (like user ID) will be in turn unique and immutable. Or maybe you're looking for smth. like URL shortener/uglifier?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a gem, but making a URL non-changable is trivial. Just don't let the users (or developers?) change it. And unique is easy as well, just use the user ID or other unique identifier you have for the user in the URL.

Something like this:

```
"https://yourdomain.tld/directory/structure/prefix#{user.id}suffix"
```

The directory structure and prefix/suffix are, of course, optional.

Or use URI scheme, host, etc. instead of hard-coding those bits.